# "PGError: no connection to the server" after idle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, postgresql

After my application sits idle overnight, when I try to access it in the morning I get a 500 Internal server error and the logs indicate "PGError: no connection to the server". After this first request if I refresh the page again everything is fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with apache 2, Passenger 3.0.2, Rails 2.3.8, and Postgres 8.4 on a remote server.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the log:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 192.168.1.33 at 2011-01-06 17:28:14) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"da"}
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: no connection to the server
: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1)  LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:47:in `current_user'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:51:in `set_current_user'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:123:in `render_optional_error_file'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.2) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Jan 06 17:28:14 -0700 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  PGError: no connection to the server
: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1)  LIMIT 1
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:221:in `log'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:520:in `execute'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1002:in `select_raw'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:989:in `select'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all_without_query_cache'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:81:in `cache_sql'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:60:in `select_all'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:664:in `find_by_sql'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1578:in `find_every'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1535:in `find_initial'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:616:in `find'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1910:in `find_by_id'
    /home/user/application/releases/20110106230903/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:47:in `current_user'
    /home/user/application/releases/20110106230903/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:51:in `set_current_user'
    /home/user/application/releases/20110106230903/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:123:in `render_optional_error_file'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:97:in `rescue_action_in_public'
    /home/user/application/releases/20110106230903/vendor/plugins/exception_notification/lib/exception_notification/notifiable.rb:48:in `rescue_action_in_public'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:154:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:74:in `rescue_action'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in `call_with_exception'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in `dispatch'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Comment: I actually figured it out, I should have replied earlier:
In Ubuntu the default value for tcp_keepalive_time (The number of seconds a connection needs to be idle  before  TCP begins sending out keep-alive probes.) is 2 hours. My switch is set to timeout idle connections after 15 minutes. I just set my switch to keep idle connections on port 5432 alive for greater than 2 hours and my problem was solved.
Basic mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this whilst researching my own version of this problem.  It looks as if you are using the fork method in the spawn library (perhaps part of Phusion Passenger?), which does not appear to be Postgres compatible at this moment.

I hope this provides a possible clue for you and/or the next visitor.

Comment: Do you have any more info about this?  Is this a fork spawn in Postgres, in Rails, in Ruby, in Passenger, or what?  How can I disable it?

Answer (score -1):

Try turning off SSL database connections by adding this line to your database.yml file:

```
sslmode: disable
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this, but do you have any more information? I assume the problem is that the SSL connection is timing out? Is there another way to deal with this and still use SSL? I'm dealing with sensitive data here and I would prefer to keep the connection as secure as possible.

Comment: Sorry to say that this did not work. Thanks for the try though. Any other ideas?