# Rails produces "PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly" after some timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, timeout, connection

I have the setup of my Rails app as following:

- Rails: 3.0.5 (under Apache proxy) running on RHEL 5.6
- Postgres: 8.4, running on Windows Server 2008
  The 2 servers are on the same LAN.

The problem is, after some idle time, when I make a new request to the Rails app, it gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

From what I have researched, it seems that the database connections are dropped after some timeout by Postgres. During this time, from the Rails side,

- if I make a request to Rails (1st request), it will display the connection error as above
- if I make another request to Rails (2nd request), Rails seems to reconnect to Postgres and functions correctly.

It means that I will always experience the first connection error then will have all normal operation again, which is very serious in my case since I'd like to deliver a non-error response to my client.

I have looked in following questions and answers, but they do not seem to be appropriate for my case:

- ["PGError: no connection to the server" after idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675380/pgerror-no-connection-to-the-server-after-idle) (Ubuntu for DB server)
- [How to use tcp_keepalives settings in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166872/how-to-use-tcp-keepalives-settings-in-postgresql) (keepalives in MacOS)

Do you have any advice in order to make my app free from db connection errors? Thank you.

Comment: I am getting same error while using postgresql with heroku

Comment: It is normal for connections to go away. It is not normal for Rails to treat it so ungracefully. Check your database driver (adapter)'s implementation of `verify!` and `active?`; normally `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool` gives the adapter a chance to reconnect any stale connection immediately prior to checking it out from the pool.  Which gem are you using for Postgres?

Answer (score 5):

We had this problem on Heroku, a lot.  As a hackish solution, here's what we did.  Put the following in your ApplicationController:

```rb
prepend_before_filter :confirm_connection
def confirm_connection
  c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  begin
    c.select_all "SELECT 1"
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.warn "Reconnecting to database"
    c.reconnect!
  end
end
```

Basically, tests the connection on each controller hit.  Scalable?  Not really.  But it fixed the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

In database.yml, do you have the `reconnect: true` option set for the connection? ex:

```
production:
  adapter:   postgresql
  database:  myapp
  username:  deploy
  password:  password
  reconnect: true
```

I'm not sure about the specific error, but without this option you need to handle a class of expected db errors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while going live on **production**.I just opened my production console and tried to connect the PG db and it worked.

```
 RAILS_ENV=production rails c
 User.new
```

and it worked after this.

hope it helps someone ;)